# Как сделать плавную замену val() а не всего элемента?

Tags: jquery

Как сделать плавную замену value? а не всего блока

```js
$('.wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
  let thisButton = $(this);

  // Исчезает весь элемент
  thisButton.val('').fadeOut(500);

  // Вот это должно плавно появиться
  thisButton.val("Отправляется").fadeIn(500);

  setTimeout(function() {

    // После 2х секунд, value плавно появляется обратно
    thisButton.val("Отправить").fadeIn(500);
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="wpcf7-submit" type="submit" value="Отправить">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо input используйте button со вложенным span и для него делайте анимацию

```js
$('.wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
  let thisButton = $(this).find("span");

  // Исчезает весь элемент
  thisButton.fadeOut(500);

  // Вот это должно плавно появиться
  thisButton.html("Отправляется").fadeIn(500);

  setTimeout(function() {

    // После 2х секунд, value плавно появляется обратно
    thisButton.html("Отправить").fadeIn(500);
  }, 2000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="wpcf7-submit" type="submit"><span>Отправить<span></button>
```

Comment: Хорошее альтернативное решение.

Comment: val все-таки не анимировать?

Comment: val это не отдельный элемент, а лишь атрибут. У него нет ни ширины, ни высоты, ни прозрачности, он только вмещает значение. Как вы себе представляете его анимацию, если он настолько неопределенный? Лично я не встречала что-либо подобного.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение. это то, что нужно было